# How to play a sound on background notifications with firebase-messaging-sw.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

```js
let sound = new Audio("");
```

when I use this code in `firebase-messaginf-sw.js` file for service worker I Get reference error.

when notification come in background I get notification but I get reference error  Audio is not defined.
I tried many ways but they didn't work.

Comment: Well, the error clearly states the issue: you didn't define the sound for your audio, you reference nothing. So, instead of `let sound = new Audio("")`, you have to have the path defined: `let sound = new Audio("/path/to/your/file.mp3")` and then you can use all the available methods, like `sound.play()`, `sound.pause()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `Audio` constructor is exposed to Window objects only, which is why it is undefined in other contexts like service workers.

This can be confirmed by looking at the [IDL definition for `Audio`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#the-audio-element):

```
[Exposed=Window,
 LegacyFactoryFunction=Audio(optional DOMString src)]
interface HTMLAudioElement : HTMLMediaElement {
  [HTMLConstructor] constructor();
};
```

As you can see, `Worker` is not exposed.

Comment: can you tell me how i can fix my issue in service worker

Comment: I think you need to add a callback on client-side using [onBackgroundMessage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/messaging_sw.md#onbackgroundmessage). You can then play sound when receiving a background notification.